# Confusion on Flattening a Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I was doing this Leetcode problem where it asks to flatten a tree (see: https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list) and this is the code I had but I'm confused why the output seems to be returning the same original tree. Am I not directly modifying the tree itself to return? What do I seem to be missing?

```
class Solution {
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {

        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        Stack<TreeNode> stk = new Stack<>();
        TreeNode trk = null;
        TreeNode curr = root;

        while (!stk.isEmpty()) {

            while (curr != null) {
                stk.push(curr);

                if (trk == null) {
                    trk = root;
                } else {
                    trk.left = null;
                    trk.right = curr;
                    trk = trk.right;
                }
                curr = curr.left;
            }

            curr = stk.pop();
            curr = curr.right;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using recursion, not a stack. When you come back to a node after doing its left child, how do you know to go to the right child, not up?

Comment: If you use recursion to do a DFS collecting the nodes in pre-order, then you can just iterate over the resulting pre-order and attach the nodes to each other as right children

Comment: @rkechols Well, I always go right until right is a null, else I pop. Isn't that the premise of the pre-order traversal? To visit middle node, then left, then right.

Comment: @rkechols Yea, I get that but I still don't comprehend why my solution isn't valid. I'm ultimately doing the same thing (recursion calls still end up taking up memory space for each call so it's not much different from having a physical stack data structure) and am modifying the structure. I'm just confused where I went wrong because I'm used to functions that return physical values. In this case, the return type is void so it just wants you to flatten / modify the existing tree.

Comment: I haven't taken it to a debugger, but I bet the problem is that you're exciting the tree while you're traversing it. Not good

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found my error. Among some issues with how I was traversing and updating the pointers which was leading to a cycle formation in the tree, the biggest and most glaring issue was that I never pushed anything to the stack initially so the `while (!stk.isEmpty())` never gets called and it just pretty much returns the original tree. Dumb of me haha.